# Set a navigation node in the impex to have no anchor / be a heading

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am working on a navigation IMPEX for hybris (not really confident with it, sorry!), and would like to have some of the nodes be headings rather than a link. Setting them with no link reference means that go nowhere but they are still anchors and hence the cursor changes, confusing users. Is this possible from the IMPEX file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to modify the navigationbarcomponent.jsp.

Check the link has url then call linkcomponent or else just place the name of the link.